# How can I assign macros to my keyboard keys on Ubuntu, similar to Razer Keyboard Macros in Windows?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I had Windows, I had a software called "Razer Synapse" which let me assign macros to my keyboard keys.

My keyboard is a Razer BlackWidow and it has 5 additional keys that I used to assign my username, email, etc to, instead of having to type everything whenever I needed them.

Is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does anything in this question help you? http://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux

Comment: Well you can just assign a custom short cut.